# Google Play Console access api section not loading

Tags: google-play-console

I am the owner of the account on Google Play Console.  When I try to link a GCP project by going to Settings -> Access API, the page just shows this message:

```
The API access page has gone away
We've made some updates to our API setup, which means that the API access page has gone away. If you've already set up API access, there's nothing you need to do, and your existing integrations will continue to work.
```

Does anyone know why this is?  I cannot find anything online referring to this.  I am definitely the account owner.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a sneaky update and haven't found any announcement or documentation. Hundreds of tools and their docs refer to old linking approach.

Looks like this the new navigation to link play console with cloud project, https://help.radio.co/en/articles/6232140-how-to-get-your-google-play-json-key

Comment: I emailed customer support and they said that it was no longer necessary.  You just have to enable Google Play Developer API on a GCP and use service credentials.  It will work without linking.

Comment: I wrote an article about it, to make the situation clear for the community and everyone else who faces this issue https://medium.com/@berteodosio/you-no-longer-need-to-have-a-gcp-project-associated-with-your-google-play-developer-account-to-c81e75ee1aff